# Logging interceptor is not working

Tags: spring-boot, interceptor

The issue is that it seems like interceptor is not called.

```
@Component
public class LoggingInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

    @Overridegre
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object, Exception arg3)
            throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Request Completed!");
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object, ModelAndView model)
            throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Method executed");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Before process request");
        return true;
    }

}

@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    LoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);
    }
}
```

I've found examples but they are not working !

I'm trying to add start and end log and also performance log. Any idea please ?

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.sofelite.proj.controllers" })
public class ProjApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(GrentyApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(GrentyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is the Application class
Please note that in com.sofelite.proj I have all application packages such as controllers and interceptors.

Comment: Try to do `registry.addInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor);`

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not working.

Comment: Did you check breakpoint at `public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);
    }`

Comment: Yes the debugger doesn't stop.

Comment: Please, share your application configuration, I should look at `@ComponentScan`

Comment: Please check my edit.

Comment: Try remove ".controllers" from scan packages to give spring scan all of your classes for components and services.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works now !!

Comment: It will be pleasure mark the comment as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is working:

```java
     @Configuration
       public class LoggingConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {  

         @Override
         public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
            registry.addInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor());
         }
   
     }
```

and the LoggingInterceptor class:

```java
    @Component
    public class LoggingInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

       private static final Logger LOGGER = 
     LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingInterceptor.class);

      @Override
      public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
      Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        LOGGER.info("Request URL: " + request.getRequestURL());
        LOGGER.info("Start Time: " + System.currentTimeMillis());

        request.setAttribute("startTime", startTime);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
            Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
         sb.append("!Status: "+response.getStatus()+"\n");
         sb.append("!URL: "+ request.getRequestURL());
         sb.append("!Method: " + request.getMethod() + "\n");
         LOGGER.info(sb.toString());

    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("URL Request Completed. End Time: "+ endTime);
    }
  }
```